# NHibernate in NServiceBus - IList<T> or List<T>

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

I have a problem with NServiceBus where I first get the error that NHibernate cannot map from an NHibernate specific Bag, and when I make this an IList, I get a message that NHibernate cannot find a concrete implementation for this IList. I am stumped.

This is the first error I got:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[CustomerDirect.Interfaces.Document.DocumentSubTemplate]'
to type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CustomerDirect.Interfaces.Document.DocumentSubTemplate]'.
at (Object , Object[] , SetterCallback )    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.WrapVisitor.ProcessComponent(Object
component, IAbstractComponentType componentType)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.WrapVisitor.ProcessComponent(Object
component, IAbstractComponentType componentType)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.WrapVisitor.ProcessValue(Int32 i, Object[]
values, IType[] types)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessEntityPropertyValues(Object[]
values, IType[] types)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.VisitCollectionsBeforeSave(Object
entity, Object id, Object[] values, IType[] types, IEventSource
source)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object
entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean
useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean
requiresImmediateIdAccess)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object
entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source,
Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent
event)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent
event)    at
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent
event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent
event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)    at
NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.SharedConnectionStorageSessionProvider.ExecuteInTransaction(Action`1
operation) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\SharedConnectionStorageSessionProvider.cs:line
60    at NServiceBus.SagaPersistenceBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Sagas\SagaPersistenceBehavior.cs:line
116    at
ServiceControl.Plugin.SagaAudit.CaptureSagaStateBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5d8e2b68f32aa08f\src\ServiceControl.Plugin.SagaAudit\CaptureSagaStateBehavior.cs:line
41    at
NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.OpenNativeTransactionBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\OpenNativeTransactionBehavior.cs:line
20    at
NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.OpenSessionBehavior.InnerInvoke(BehaviorContext
context, Action next, Func`1 connectionRetriever) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\OpenSessionBehavior.cs:line
73    at
NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.OpenSessionBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\OpenSessionBehavior.cs:line
35    at NServiceBus.DataBusReceiveBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\DataBus\DataBusReceiveBehavior.cs:line
60    at
NServiceBus.SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\SetCurrentMessageBeingHandledBehavior.cs:line
17    at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line
46    at
NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line
23    at
NServiceBus.ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExecuteLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
24    at NServiceBus.CallbackInvocationBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\CallbackInvocationBehavior.cs:line
22    at
NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
47    at
NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line
20    at
NServiceBus.SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Subscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.cs:line
32    at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line
42    at
NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.OpenSqlConnectionBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\OpenSqlConnectionBehavior.cs:line
38    at NServiceBus.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line
17    at
NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext
context, Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Monitoring\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line
23    at NServiceBus.AuditBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context,
Action next) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Audit\AuditBehavior.cs:line
20    at
NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1
pipelineAction, T context) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
127    at
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage
message) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
344    at
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessage
message) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
230    at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line
266
```

Then, when I made my property an IList, I got this:

```
Exception when starting endpoint.

NHibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[CustomerDirect.Interfaces.Document.DocumentSubTemplate,
CustomerDirect.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, for columns:
NHibernate.Mapping.Column(SubTemplates)

   at NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.get_Type()

   at
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingLogExtensions.LogMapped(Property
property, IInternalLogger log)

   at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.PropertiesBinder.Bind(IEnumerable`1
properties, Table table, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas, Action`1
modifier, Action`1 addToModelAction)

   at
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.BindCompositeElement(HbmCompositeElement
compositeElementMapping, Collection model, IDictionary`2
inheritedMetas)

   at
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.BindCollectionSecondPass(ICollectionPropertiesMapping
collectionMapping, Collection model, IDictionary`2 persistentClasses,
IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)

   at
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.<>c__DisplayClass13.<AddCollectionSecondPass>b__12(IDictionary`2
persistentClasses)

   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile()

   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()

   at
NServiceBus.Features.NHibernateStorageSession.Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext
context) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\NHibernateStorageSession.cs:line
54

   at
NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(FeatureState
featureState, IEnumerable`1 featuresToActivate,
FeatureConfigurationContext context) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:line
235

   at
NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(FeatureConfigurationContext
context) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:line
116

   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in
c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:line
115

   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1
moreConfiguration) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line
119

   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Start() in
c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line
58
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't see how I can manage the mappings myself. I am using the NSericeBus.NHibernate package which handles this for me.
If anyone can tell me how I can provide my own mapping that would help a lot.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code for the saga data class and any related to it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using NHibernate Loquacious mapping. Since we never query on our Saga data other than the ID of the saga itself, I went with having the complex properties as Json in nvarchar(max) fields. I used this gist to get it to work: https://gist.github.com/phillip-haydon/1936188